# Calculate $L^p$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider $u_n(x)=e^{inx}\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$.

Is $\vert\vert u_n\vert\vert_{L^p}=1$ true?
I only find results for an upper integral bound $2\pi$...

Comment: Are you aware that you should take the modulus of the function before integrating to get the $L^p$ norm?

Comment: Sorry but what do. you mean with Modulus in that case?

Comment: $||f ||_{L^p(\Omega)} = (\int_\Omega |f|^p)^{1/p}$. Notice I used $|f|$ in the integral, not $f$.